# Is developing iPhone apps in any language other than Objective-C ever a truly viable solution?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I hear all this stuff about crazy ways to build iPhone apps using Ruby or C# under .NET or the like. Even stuff about developing apps on Windows using Java, or auto-generated apps using Flash CS5 or something.

Now, I've never really spent any time at all investigating these claims—I just brushed them off as clumsy or cumbersome or downright claptrap—but I'm a proud Objective-C programmer who's perhaps a little worried as to whether there's any truth in all of this?

Comment: This question has been asked many times. Short answer: yes there are several other ways of developing apps for the iPhone. MonoTouch for working with the Cocoa frameworks. Corona, Unity3D, Torque etc for making 2D or 3D games, using Lua, Javascript or other languages. And yes, also CS5. Apple is getting more aggressive and especially wants to keep Flash off of the iPhone, but at the same time they are encouraging others of the abovementioned, so they're policy is basically "we decide".

Comment: The JS/CSS/HTML5/local storage option is viable in the sense that it works, bypasses the App Store approval process, is Apple-sanctioned and likely to remain so. Whether it is really viable for any given purpose is a different matter -- you probably wouldn't want to do much heavy lifting -- but there are plenty of frankly underachieving apps in the store that could probably be done this way. Persuading people to fork over cash for such things is left as an exercise for the reader...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the newest iPhone OS license agreement by Apple, all apps for the iPad, iPhone, iPod must be either built with XCode/ObjectiveC directly, or be built using HTML/CS/JS (With libraries like PhoneGap if desired). The Flash CS5 to iPhone cross compiler has been pretty much expressly forbidden. You can read about it [from Steve Jobs](http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/).

I guess the only time those tools would be viable is in a corporate environment, where you were installing the apps directly on the phones.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, Apple is actively blocking apps developed with tools like you mention from appearing in the App store. That makes whether it is possible pretty much irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that if this is possible it will soon be stamped out by Apple.  They are very aggressive with their licensing terms.